# BLOB GET API call being made when typing in CustomInput field

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I noticed that whenever I type in the CustomInput field of my website, there's a BLOB GET API call being made for the media files that are uploaded

This is causing the media files uploaded to flicker/refresh every time a user types something.

I would want to avoid this from happening.

This is the code for the CustomInput field where I am typing a name:

```
          <HorizontalDivider/>
          <FormControl mt={5} mb={5}>
            <CustomInput
              value={name}
              type="text"
              onChange={(e)=> {set_name(e.target.value)}}
              placeholder="Enter a name..."
              size="lg"
            />
          </FormControl>
```

This is the code for where the media file is being uploaded:

```
          <HorizontalDivider/>
          <Text color="white" fontSize={"20px"} mt={5}><b>You may upload 1 video or up to 10 images. Our maxiumum file size for videos are 4GB, and images should be a max of 50MB each. If you have content that is over 4GB we recommend compressing for an optimal uploading experience.</b></Text>

          <Text color="white" mt={5}>Image file types supported:<b>.jpeg, .png, .gif </b> <br/> Video file types supported: <b>.mp4, .avi or .wmv</b></Text>

          <br/>
          {media.length > 0
            ? (
              <>
              <PreviewMediaGrid content={media} type={'content'}/>

              <FormControl mt={5} mb={5}>
                <form action="#" encType="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                  <CustomFileInputAddMore htmlFor="file-upload">
                    <Flex align={'center'}>
                      <FaUpload color="white" size="20px"/>
                      <Text color="white" fontSize="20px" style={{textAlign:"center", marginLeft:15}}>Select Media...</Text>
                    </Flex>
                  <input id="file-upload" type="file" onChange={(e:any)=> addFiles(e)} multiple />
                  </CustomFileInputAddMore>
                  </form>
                </FormControl>
              </>
            )
            : (
            <FormControl mt={5} mb={5}>
              <form action="#" encType="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <CustomFileInput>
                <label htmlFor="file-upload">
                  <Center><FaUpload color="white" size="175px"/></Center>
                  <Text color="white" fontSize="3xl" style={{textAlign:"center", marginTop:15}}>Upload Photos / Video</Text>
                </label>
                <input id="file-upload" type="file" onChange={(e:any)=> addFiles(e)} multiple />
                </CustomFileInput>
                </form>
              </FormControl>
            )
          }
```

These are the BLOB GET API calls being made whenever I type something in the CustomInput field:
[image: API calls]

Thank you

Comment: What is set_name doing and what interacts with that state? Post all related code please

Comment: @Abe So `set_name` is basically setting the name:

`const [name, set_name] = React.useState('');`

Comment: do you have a useEffect that watches that state?  Post the whole component please, not just the JSX